# how to specify custom template for a kendo ui grid edit command link

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am struggling to get a custom edit command link working for kendo ui grid. Say I have following grid

```
<div id="request-grid" style="height: 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#request-grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        columns: [{
            field: "Id", title: "Id", width: 20
        }, {
            field: "FromName", title: "Req Name", width: 150
        ....
        }, {
            command: [{ name: "edit", template: kendo.template('@Html.ActionLink("Edit","_SoftwareRequestEdit","SoftwareRequest",new {id = "#= Id #"}, null)') }]
        }],
    });
</script>
```

I have used the code above for the **edit link**, but I don't remember the specifics. I have been scratching my head for the correct syntax for 2 hours now and still couldn't figure out. The above **edit command template** generates following link

```
<a href="/Admin/SoftwareRequest/_SoftwareRequestEdit/%23%3d%20Id%20%23">Edit</a>
```

whereas I was expecting this

```
<a href="/Admin/SoftwareRequest/_SoftwareRequestEdit/3">Edit</a>
```

for grid row with **Id equal to 3**

Any ideas how to correctly generate **edit links** with correct **Id** values

Comment: Did you get a good solution for this?  I am getting pretty tired of jumping from Kendo UI grids to MVC Grids on every other page because one can encode/do something the other cannot.  This is going to be a nightmare to manage.  Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `kendo.template()` from the definition of the template, KendoUI already knows that it has to be a template so it expects a `string` and not a kendo.template` object. See documentation and examples in their documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.template).

Example:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [ {
        field: "name",
        template: "<strong>#: name # </strong>"
    }],
    dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" } ]
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to use the ActionLink directly instead of passing it to kendo.template(). However, it prints out the same link shown in question. I think there is some encoding going on in asp.net MVC syntax for the actionlink and it looks like the MVC is replacing the hash (#) with an encoded value although I am not very sure about this. Anyway removing the kendo.template() produces no difference.